# Need the title for a short story about the US losing a war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story probably dates from the 1970s, and I recall it being written like a historian's account. In the story, the US lost a war to a Latin American country, probably Mexico.

The one passage I recall went something like this:

> Presidente Gonzales said, "My generals, win me this war!" A large book does not have room to contain the requirements placed on the US military by OSHA, the labor unions, the National Organization for Women, the ...

@Praxis: It was likely in Analog or one of the other monthly SF magazines available at the time. Back then, it seemed as though a number of published stories had little in the way of obviously fantastic elements. This was probably a "social commentary" story of the "if this goes on" type.

Comment: Maybe I have read over your question too quickly, but what are the science fiction / fantasy elements?

Comment: @Praxis Alternate history is a branch of SF.

Comment: @Praxis So I guess you don't consider *Lord of the Flies* to be science fiction? *1984* just barely qualifies on account of O'Brien's torture machine?

Comment: I know this one, but I am going to have to think about what it is. Maybe by Pohl.

Comment: @user14111 *Lord of the Flies* is science fiction?

Comment: @ChrisSunami Sure. Stories of future nuclear war and its consequences, like *Lord of the Flies* and *On the Beach*, I consider them a subgenre of science fiction. Of course, if you define "science fiction" as "stories with rayguns, spaceships, and space monsters", then it's not science fiction.

Comment: I guess *Nam* is a short title, not a short story.

Comment: @user14111 I get that, it's just that I read *Lord of the Flies* many years ago, and didn't remember the nuclear war aspect at all.  I had assumed it was set in the past, not the future (although perhaps it was the future relative to when it was written).  At any rate, I was just surprised that you used it as an example of a book typically classified as SF.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Oh, *Lord of the Flies* is not typically classified as SF? I didn't know that, but I don't doubt you're right. I know I don't do a very good job of keeping track of what other people think, it's all I can do just to keep track of stuff that matters.

Comment: @user14111 *Lord of the Flies* doesn't consider a future nuclear war - it considers a nuclear war in exactly the time when it was written (the middle of the Cold War), which was a realistic prospect. That part of the setting is to make explicit the "as above, so below" comparison with the Cold War - nations of adults are fighting externally, whilst the children fight on the island, both with equally childish and brutal motivations - but it does not actually affect the story. So *Lord of the Flies* does not qualify as alternate history, future war, or science fiction.

Comment: @user14111 ... *On the Beach* is very different in that the outcome of the nuclear war is actually the focus of the entire novel. It is explicitly post-apocalyptic.  That subtext could be removed from *Lord of the Flies* and the story would remain substantially unchanged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.  It's [The Engineer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63875) by Pohl and Kornbluth.  The passage is not exactly as you remembered it, but the intent is clear.

> ..we know what Mexico's Presidente Lopez said to his staff was: 'My
> generals, win me this war.' And this entire volume does not have
> enough space to record what the United States generals were told by
> the White House, the Congress as a whole, The Committee on Military
> Affairs, the Special Committee on Conduct of the War, ...

It goes on listing various bureaucratic organizations for half a page.

The story itself is not "written like a historian's account", but this passage is a quote from a history textbook that the protagonist is reading.

This story should be required reading for all engineering students.

Comment: why should it be required reading?

Comment: @NKCampbell I'm guessing Mr. Marble recommends it to engineering students not so much for the story-within-a-story about a war with Mexico as for the main story about (SPOILER) a catastrophic engineering failure.

Comment: perfect - good information to have since the question nor the answer reference an engineering disaster. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and it draws an analogy between "political generals" who lose wars and "political engineers" who cause engineering disasters.  A poignant message to those of us who worked in the Space Shuttle program.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't remember it as being as old as it is, and I thought I'd probably read it in Analog, but it must have been one of the collections. As an aside, I learned last night that searching Google and searching Google Books are not the same. Google didn't tell me anything pertinent, but Google Books pointed me to a collection of the first three issues of Infinity Science Fiction magazine. Frustratingly, it wouldn't show me the story, title, or author, just a very short but recognizable excerpt.

Comment: You're very welcome, I really had to rack my brain on this one.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke's *Superiority* might be worth a mention as well, both for its similar themes of engineering/planning failures and for the fact that it *was* required engineer reading at MIT for some time.

Comment: Spoilers should probably be left out of comments.  In answers, you have a good way to hide them, unless the reader specifically chooses to see them.  In comments, the reader may see them against their wishes.